# Why can't I multi-class?

Tags: baldurs-gate

I've read the manual (I think all of the relevant parts anyway). My main Baldur's Gate character is a specialist mage (Transmuter, Half-Elf). She is well into 2nd level and looking good as far as I can tell. Since she is not fully human, she is supposed to be able to multi-class, right? From what I can see, she should have been able to start multi-classing when she got her first promotion (from 1st level mage to 2nd). It wasn't an option when she leveled-up, and the greyed out portion of her information screen reads dual-class (which I don't want). I want to start multi-classing her to Mage/Fighter ASAP. I sure hope I don't have to start over to get the character I want, it's just now getting fun! (We just cleared out the mines and we have some money for a change, PARTY!)

Comment: Multi-classing for demi-humans is chosen when the character is created.  Dual classing for humans is chosen after a character has levelled up.

Comment: Crap..I missed that.

Comment: That's what I get by reading, "Yada, yada, yada...Oh THIS is relevent..yada, yada, relevent, yada, yada, yada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the AD&D system that Baldur's Gate is based on, non-humans can multi-class, but that is a decision that is made when the character is created.  In addition, specialist mages cannot multi-class - you can only be a generic fighter/mage, not a fighter/transmuter.  (There is a single exception to this rule for gnomish illusionists, but I cannot remember if that is in Baldur's Gate or not).

On the character creation screen for class, after all the single classes are listed, there is a button for **Multi-Class**, which allows you to select a valid multi-class for your character.

Unfortunately, once a non-human character has been created, they cannot change their classes.  The ability to change classes (dual classing) is restricted to humans only.

Comment: Specist bastards!  Oh well, she's kicking ass anyway. :)

Comment: I figured it was inattention on my part. I wanted to PLAY not read a long manual. I go back now and make lemonade, she really is doing quite well. I just wish I could conjure some hit points for her.

Comment: @Jolenealaska You can try to find ways to increase your constitution if it's really proving problematic. Later in the game, there's a tome that increases CON by 1. Just remember that for non-little people and non-fighters, there is no particular benefit to a CON above 16. I find that for mage types, you're more likely to survive by finding the best ways to not get hit at all - then hp doesn't matter much.